# Twitter Boostrap Tooltip on Slick Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I display the [Twitter Bootstrap](http://bootstrap.com/) tooltip in [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)?

As for now when I hovered each image, the tooltip is on the top of the image but it can't be displayed because the contaner/wrapper of the carousel is in positioned absolute.

[image]

**HTML** Markup for [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

```
<div class="slider center slick-initialized slick-slider">
    <div class="slick-list draggable">
        <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" style="width: 197px;">
            <img src="assets/css/images/paid-ad-2.jpg" class="img-responsive" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Aparment Unit in Arkansas">
        <div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" style="width: 197px;">
            <img src="assets/css/images/paid-ad-2.jpg" class="img-responsive" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Aparment Unit in Arkansas">
        </div><!-- And so on... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**HTML** Markup for [Twitter Bootstrap](http://bootstrap.com/) tooltip

```
<div class="tooltip fade top in" style="display: block; top: -32px; left: 49px;">
    <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
    <div class="tooltip-inner">Hidden tooltip</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slick-list {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1030;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/36zRU/

Any help would be greatly appriciated

Comment: Curious if you found an answer to this..I'm having the same trouble

Comment: Sorry brother but I'm still waiting for the answer.

Comment: I ended up just moving the position of the popover...I only spent an hour or so trying...but the answer certainly isn't obvious...

Comment: can you create a fiddle for that or maybe add your answer below, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `data-container="body"` attribute for each image [Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/heshamElghndour/36zRU/9/).

Comment: Great, Straight solution!